# Block specify Email ID (jhonedoe@gmail.com) in HTML input field?

Tags: html, forms, validation, email, input

```
   <form action="">
    
     <label for="email"> Email </label>
     <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
     <input type="submit"> submit </input>
   
   </form>
```

What pattern code I should write to validate to block a perticular email ?

Comment: You should use JavaScript for this.

Comment: Do you want to DISALLOW a particular email address? For this use JavaScript function on submit event. However if you really want to block then Server Side programming is necessary with optional client side checks.

Comment: **NB:** Many email providers, including GMail, allow users to create "alias" addresses. If you're trying to block submissions from a particular user, they'll be able to bypass your *"block this address"* check in minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much all of you for replying. I got it done with all of your help..